# I'm getting problem when setting the height of label dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm setting the tableView cells height dynamically according to labels height and labels height according to text. It is working fine when I had given text with spaces (ex: This is Question for stackoverflow). But when I'm entering text of length two lines without spaces(ex ThisisQuestionforstackoverflow) . It is taking two lines and the text is starting from second line and cutting at the end.It taking first line full space and second line like(ThisisQuestionfor.....).

I'm using methods

- +(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
- -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

In cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
float productNameHeight = [DetailsViewController calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:warObj1.productName :valueFont : valueWidth :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
UILabel *productNameValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoordinateStartLocatioForValue,yCoordinateStartLocation,valueWidth,productNameHeight)];
```

Can u plz help me quickly.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no spaces in you text, be sure to use `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap` or `UILineBreakModeClip` when both calculating the size of the UILabel and for the `lineBreakMode` property of the UILabel itself.

Answer (score 0):

What's the line break mode for the label and how many lines are you allowing it to have?

You might be correctly setting the height of the label but then telling to draw all the text on one line :)

You should check that the number of lines in the label is 0 (which means as many as needed) and the line break mode is set to character break. (It sounds like it's set to truncate end at the moment).

Comment: Hi  I had taken WordWrap line break mode and I had set label.numberoflines = 0.

Comment: I had tried characterbreak mode still same problem is occuring.

Comment: What is proudctNameHeight for 'thisisaverylongstringwithnospaces' and for 'this is a very log string with spaces' - are they the same? If they are different then it's to do with the way you are calling `calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth`